# Problema com site wordpress na migração de servidor

Tags: wordpress, servidor

Migrei um site Wordpress de servidor e agora só reconhece a página inicial, as outras páginas simplesmente da erro 500 Internal Server, alguém já teve algo parecido?

Comment: Você seguiu esse passo a passo do site oficial?

https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Movendo_o_WordPress

Comment: Ao migrar, crie uma cópia do site e faça a migração com a cópia sem tirar o site atual do ar, sempre análise as versões do WordPress dos servidores e se não compatíveis, veja as diferenças da API em relação a versão. Verifique as configurações básicas se estão corretas pois é um servidor novo, caminho de arquivo, etc

Answer (score 0):

Atualize os permalinks em "Configurações > Permalinks > Salvar". Isso vai reescrever o .htaccess. Deve funcionar.

(https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]